# NancyFx Diagnostics page returns a 404 exception

Tags: nancy

I am new to Nancy and am playing with the tracing and other diagnostics details. The documentation at https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Diagnostics states that I should be able to hit the diagnostics dashboard by using the address http:///_nancy. My app is running at http://127.0.0.1:55368/ but when I enter http://127.0.0.1:55368/_nancy, I am getting a 404 status code. Is there something else I need to do to enable the diagnostics page in nancyfx version 0.23.2? My app is only a simple api and does not use views.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The documentation on the page listed above states:

> Without the password you will be presented with a page telling you that the dashboard needs to be configured in order for you to use it, along with instructions on how to perform the configuration.

However, I received a 404 instead. Once I configured a password in the bootstrapper as per the docs, the login screen showed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app in Release mode, you'll just get a 404 straight away.  See this issue: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/625
and commit: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/commit/002bb9573c5ccd2437233f5bd518762c0ee77b35

> Updates so that StatisConfiguration.IsRunningDebug is public. The
>   DiagnosticsHook will not check that flag before returning the
>   diagnostics help view. If true then it will return NotFound instead.